# Understanding Java Thread Interference

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I'm learning Java, coming from a python background, and trying to understand thread interference, starting with the code & explanation in this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html

To reproduce interference, I have another class that starts three threads, each randomly calling either increment or decrements 10 times.

I expect, with 3 threads & 30 increments or decrements, some would overlap, and thus the final `Counter` value would not equal the `(# increments)` - `(# decrements)`.

But every time I run the code and analyze the resulting output, I find the final value to equal `(# increments)` - `(# decrements)`. Although its possible that after 5 runs, I somehow did not get any interference, its much more likely that I misunderstood the interference effect or inadvertently implemented code that avoids interference.

Here's my code:

```
// file: CounterThreads.java
public class CounterThreads {
    private static class CounterThread implements Runnable {
        private Counter c;

        CounterThread(Counter c)
        {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                try {

                    if (((int)(Math.random() * 10) % 2) == 0) {
                        System.out.format("%s - Decrementing...\n", threadName);
                        c.decrement();
                    } else {
                        System.out.format("%s - Incrementing...\n", threadName);
                        c.increment();
                    }
                    System.out.format("%s - The internal counter is at %s\n", threadName, c.value());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.format("Thread %s interrupted\n", threadName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Counter c = new Counter();
        for (int  i=0; i<3; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new CounterThread(c));
            System.out.format("Starting Thread: %s\n", t.getName());
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The file `Counter.java` contains code copied from the oracle documentation above, reproduced here for convenience

```
// file: Counter.java
public class Counter {
    private int c = 0;

    void increment ()
    {
        c++;
    }

    void decrement()
    {
        c--;
    }

    int value()
    {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: start by running a single thread and see if you obtain anything else than `0` - if you don't, then something is wrong with  your approach to detection.

Comment: To see interference you have to create actual concurrent execution.  The code you wrote performs the increment or decrement in _nanoseconds_ and then sleeps for a full second. The chances of two threads getting dispatched at exactly the same nanosecond is miniscule.  You'd need to write code that executes increment and decrement millions of times, in a tight loop, in several threads simultaneously, and checks for an unexpected value after each iteration. I.e. fetch a thread local copy of the value, inc/decrement the copy, inc/decrement the value, compare.

Comment: as long as addition and subtraction are atomic operations, `Counter` value will always be equal to `(# increments) - (# decrements)` so there's nothing surprising about that

Comment: however if you update the counter within some specific thread (say thread1) and then try to output its value, it might get updated by another thread right before the output operation, so the output will be inconsistent within the scope of thread1

Comment: Ditto what they said (above):  Get rid of the `sleep()` calls.  Also, instead of having each thread do ten operations, have each thread do ten _million_.

Comment: I think there is plenty of material out there on this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. @mangusta, thanks for what should have been obvious re: `# inc - # dec == final counter value` & what interference would manifest itself as.

Comment: If you only want to see some ACID mistake, make sure that the "atomic" operation takes some time. Like copying an array of several million entries, increase every entry and write it back, then check if the amount of increments is the amount of threads. What you found is the biggest problem of all, errors that might not occur in a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce, you need to **maximize the probability** to increment and/or decrement your counter **concurrently** (NB: it is not an easy task since incrementing/decrementing a counter is a very fast operation), which is not the case of your current code because:

1. You don't use any mechanism to synchronize the threads before incrementing/decrementing your counter.
2. You print your messages in the standard output stream too often and at the wrong place which is a problem when you know that a `PrintStream` is thread-safe and **uses an intrinsic lock to prevent concurrent accesses** which reduces the probability to increment and/or decrement your counter concurrently.
3. You add a useless long sleep which once again reduces the probability to get concurrent modifications of your counter.
4. You don't use as many threads as you can.

So, your code should be rewritten a little bit to fix the previous problems.

To fix #1, you can use a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) to make sure that all your threads reach the same barrier point (located just before incrementing/decrementing your counter) before going any further.

To fix #2, I would recommend to keep only one message **after** having incremented/decremented your counter.

To fix #3, I would simply remove it as it is useless anyway.

To fix #4, I would use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` as amount of threads to use since it will use as many processors as you have on your local machine which should be enough for such kind of task.

So the final code could then be:

**Counter**

```
public class Counter {
    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private int c;

    public Counter(int threads) {
        this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(threads);
    }

    void await() throws BrokenBarrierException, InterruptedException {
        barrier.await();
    }
    ...
}
```

**The `main` method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    Counter c = new Counter(threads);
    for (int  i=0; i<threads; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**The `for` loop of the `run` method**

```
try {
    // Boolean used to know if the counter has been decremented or not
    // It has been moved before the await to avoid doing anything before
    // incrementing/decrementing the counter
    boolean decrementing = (int)(Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0;
    // Wait until all threads reach this point
    c.await();
    if (decrementing) {
        c.decrement();
    } else {
        c.increment();
    }
    // Print the message
    System.out.format(
        "%s - The internal counter is at %d %s\n", 
        threadName, c.value(), decrementing ? "Decrementing" : "Incrementing"
    );

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.format("Thread %s in error\n", threadName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't fully understood `CyclicBarrier`, but I implemented the your snippets & can see the interference clearly.

Comment: I don't see how `Counter.await` gets invoked, thus where the barrier gets used. I tried adding this line to `Counter.await` just before `barrier.await();`, `System.out.println("Calling Barrier");` but nothing gets printed to the console